# WPF databinding issue for itemsControl in usercontrol

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, itemscontrol

I have two classes and a usercontrol.

```
class pvalue
{
    public string value;
    public bool selected;
    public pvalue(string v, bool s)
    {
        value = v;
        selected = s;
    }
}

class param
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string prefix { get; set; }
    public IList<pvalue> values { get; set; }   

    public param(string _name, string _prefix, IList<pvalue> _values)
    {
        name = _name;
        prefix = _prefix;
        values = _values;
    }
}


<UserControl DataContext="{Binding param}" >
 <Grid>...
    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemctl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=values}">
    ...
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=selected}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=value}" />
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>               
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My intention is to create the class in the application, and set it up as the datacontext of the usercontrol. But I'm very new to WPF, this is a bit over my head. The databinding isn't working - "BindingExpression path error: 'value' property not found on 'object' ''pvalue'".

Can I get some help sort out the databinding for the usercontrol? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your Solution Namespace in the UserControl definition and then include the class as a resource in Resources like this

`<UserControl.Resources>
     <param:SolutionName x:key="Param" />
</UserControl.Resources>`

Then Modify your code like following

`<UserControl DataContext="{Binding param}" >
 <Grid>...
    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemctl" ItemsSource="{Binding Source="{StaticResource Param}">
    ...
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=selected}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=value}" />
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a few things wrong here:

- You should be binding to properties (with getters and setters) and not fields, so change your public fields to properties on your pvalue type.
- If you want the UI to update when those property values change, look into implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your pvalue and param types
- I would use PascalCase for your class names and properties
- Remove the underscores from your parameter names
- Make your pvalue parameter names more descriptive
- You are binding the DataContext of the UserControl to what looks like a type name (param), how did you intend the usercontrol from getting an instance of your param type?  Normally, you might do this as a dependency property of your usercontrol, then when you consume that control, you can bind the Param dependency property of your usercontrol to a property returning an instance of your param type on your current DataContext (usually a ViewModel if using MVVM)

Comment: Thanks, good points. The test case is actually working after I fixed the property declaration of the class pvalue.